# Apache Camel: Spring WS SOAP Operation did not match

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

I am trying to create a Spring WS consumer like this:

```
<route>
            <from uri="direct:start"/>
            <to uri="spring-ws:rootqname:http://{ip}:{port}/PORTAL/webservices/A20?soapAction=acceptMessage"/>
            <to uri="log:output"/>
        </route>
```

**Error:**
`SOAPAction http://{ip}:{port}/PORTAL/webservices/A20/acceptMessage does not match an operation`

Answer (score 0):

In your property placeholders you need to use double braces like so:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <to uri="spring-ws:rootqname:http://{{ip}}:{{port}}/PORTAL/webservices/A20?soapAction=acceptMessage"/>
    <to uri="log:output"/>
</route>
```

More info here: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: Oh you got me wrong. I have hardcoded the ip and port values. Just do not want to reveal it here.